# subsets of maximum size in java given a constraint

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a arraylist of integer array as follows-

```
27 14 62 
15 92 15 
16 40 90 
61 23 78 
23 70 90 
25 93 98
```

I want to find all the subsets of maximum size such that

```
 a1[0]<a2[0] && a1[1]<a2[1] && a1[2] <a2[2]
```

What I did-
1) I sorted each row of the arraylist in ascending order.
2) Then I sorted the entire arraylist using comparator
So I get this-

```
14 27 62 
15 85 92 
16 40 90 
23 61 78 
23 70 90 
25 93 98
```

But now, I am stuck. I am not sure how to find all the subsets of maximum size subject to the above mentioned constraint. 
For example in the above case,-

```
14 27 62 
15 85 92 
25 93 98

14 27 62     
23 61 78  
25 93 98

14 27 62 
23 70 90 
25 93 98
```

are the maximum size subsets possible.

Comment: Did you try brute-force? Just checking every valid combination?

Comment: No I was not sure how to get all the combinations, brute-force would be exponential in time-complexity but I think it would work for small numbers but I am not sure how to proceed

Comment: You could continue with writing a method which gets two Arrays and returns a boolean. It checks if the first array has at every index a smaller value than the second

Comment: Why is `14 27 62` `16 40 90` `25 93 98` not contained in your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this algorithm:

1. For each `row`, start tracking a `subset`
2. For each subsequent `row2`

   1. If `row < row2`, then add to the subset, and recursively continue from step 2
3. Compare the size of `subset` with any previously saved subset:

   1. If greater, then delete all previously saved subsets, and save this one
   2. If equal, then add this subset to the list of previously saved subsets

Although the time complexity of this algorithm is exponential, it's fairly easy to implement, and may be good enough for smaller datasets.

```
List<List<int[]>> findMaximumSubsets(int[][] arr) {
    List<List<int[]>> acc = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        findMaximumSubsets(arr, i, acc, new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(arr[i])));
    }
    return acc;
}

void findMaximumSubsets(int[][] arr, int row, List<List<int[]>> acc, List<int[]> current) {
    for (int i = row + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (comparator.compare(arr[row], arr[i]) < 0) {
            // ... (not spoiling for you ...)
        }
    }
}

Comparator<int[]> comparator = new Comparator<int[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
        int cmp1 = Integer.compare(a1[0], a2[0]);
        if (cmp1 > -1) {
            return 0;
        }
        int cmp2 = Integer.compare(a1[1], a2[1]);
        if (cmp2 > -1) {
            return 0;
        }
        return Integer.compare(a1[2], a2[2]);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it really allowed to sort the individual arrays before checking the constraint? The following algorithm should work either way.

The following algorithm should work in O(n<sup>2</sup>) to find one maximum set (do you need all? In that case the worst case effort is exponential):

1. build a directed acyclic graph where the individual arrays are the nodes and there is an edge between node a and b if and only if b may follow a according to the constraint.
2. make a topological sort of this graph.
3. step through the nodes in sort order (starting at the "smallest" node) and calculate for each node x the largest subset that has x as the "largest" node. This can be done by looking at all the previous nodes y: initialize with a subset that just contains x, then for all y: if x may follow y add x to the largest subset calculated for y, if this subset is larger than a previous subset for x remember it as largest.
4. in a linear pass through all the nodes find the overall largest subset.

Example:

```
14 27 62 
15 85 92 
16 40 90 
23 61 78 
23 70 90 
25 93 98
```

is already in topological order. So we calculate line by line:

```
14 27 62 -> 14 27 62
15 85 92 -> 14 27 62, 15 85 92
16 40 90 -> 14 27 62, 16 40 90
23 61 78 -> 14 27 62, 23 61 78
23 70 90 -> 14 27 62, 23 70 90
25 93 98 -> 14 27 62, 15 85 92, 25 93 98
```